# Creating a new record in one-to-many relation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I am trying to create an app in which we can ask questions and a question have many answers. So I used one-to-many association here.
Now I have two models Question Answer and two controllers questions & answers.
I have a form in the \questions\show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @answer, :url => "answer", :method => 'post' do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %> #this i am not sure about 
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

The show method in controller is:

```
  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answers = @question.answers
    @answer = Answer.new
  end
```

I also created a route to answers controller's create method

```
post 'questions/show/answer' => "answers#create"
```

Now the problem is that the question_id is passed as string but I want it to be passed as integer so that I can associate it to the current Question.
How can I do it, or is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new` action in your controller to render a new object of answer for your form, then in `create` action, find the question you want to answer and create the answer under it. Like so:

```
def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @question_created = @question.answers.create(answers_params).save

  if @question_created
    // do something or redirect somewhere
  end
end

private

def answers_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:content)
end
```

Then in your routes, you can use resources to create RESTful routes needed

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

(**Note**: each action should be used for the specific required purpose, except in instances when you want to make AJAX calls to get a form in the show action)

Comment: I have the form running in another controller's view , i.e; my form_for(@answer) is in questions controller's show.html.erb view .. does this affect the code you just gave me

Comment: It should not. Try out using the create action in answers controller with the code I provided above.